# How to show year only where necessary on date axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm writing code in R that uses ggplot2 to generate several bar graphs based on test data from several trainings, spanning (at present) about a year, like the following:

[image]

Currently all the dates are formatted "mon DD YYYY" (`"%b %d %Y"` as a Date format):

```
c("Oct 05 2020", "Nov 02 2020", "Nov 30 2020", "Jan 11 2021", "Feb 22 2021",
"Mar 08 2021", "Mar 29 2021", "Apr 12 2021", "May 03 2021", "May 17 2021")
```

But I'd like to only display the year on the first date, and any subsequent dates that are the first date in a year:

```
c("Oct 05 2020", "Nov 02", "Nov 30", "Jan 11 2021", "Feb 22", "Mar 08", "Mar 29",
"Apr 12", "May 03", "May 17")
```

Is there a way to do this, either via some kind of filtering of the Date column or something in ggplot?

Comment: You may wrap the below solution as a function and apply this while using `scale_x_date` etc.  As you didn't show a reproducible example to plot, I cannot est it

Answer (score 0):

We could convert the vector of date into `Date` class ('v1'), extract the 'Year' component, create a logical vector with `duplicated`, use that index ('i1') to replace the values in the original vector with `format`ted `Date`s from 'v2'

```
v2 <- as.Date(v1, '%b %d %Y')
i1 <- duplicated(format(v2, '%Y'))
v1[i1] <- format(v2[i1], '%b %d')
```

-ouptut

```
v1
 [1] "Oct 05 2020" "Nov 02"      "Nov 30"    
 [4] "Jan 11 2021" "Feb 22"      "Mar 08"      "Mar 29"   
 [8]   "Apr 12"      "May 03"      "May 17"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Oct 05 2020", "Nov 02 2020", "Nov 30 2020", "Jan 11 2021", "Feb 22 2021",
"Mar 08 2021", "Mar 29 2021", "Apr 12 2021", "May 03 2021", "May 17 2021")
```